# How to you remove the seal from a Deore XT FH-M8000 freehub?

Tags: maintenance, shimano, freehub

When first installing (or overhauling) Shimano rear hubs, I usually pull the freehub, lift the seal off the back side (where the splines are that engage the hub body) and then heat the freehub with a heat gun. When the old lube flows out, I drip in enough Phil's Tenacious oil to keep the things utterly silent. I love silent coasting. I have had no trouble doing this with Deore LX freehubs and others, but the FH-M8000 XTs I've got don't seem to want to give up the seal. Usually, gently picking the rubber seal with a large (not too sharp) sewing needle lets you pop it right off, but these don't seem to want to budge. Anyone out there pull one of these rear seals and know how it's done?

Comment: Just don't do it. You may only destroy the seal and gain nothing. Especially on a new hub.

Comment: Not true. You gain silence. Obviously, I'm not going to destroy the thing picking it out -- that's the entire point of this question, to see if anyone's got a tool or method that removes it without wrecking it. It's simple enough on most hubs. This one is different, but it had to be pressed in somehow.

Answer (score -2):

I would take the hub to your local bike repair shop. More than likely they will pull out a special tool just for this issue of your seal not wanting to unfasten itself.

Comment: This answer would be much better if you could describe the special tool, or show a photo of one.  A part number would be okay so OP can search for that.  "Take it to a bike shop" could be an answer to almost every question on this site.

Comment: I'd like to know which tool it is too, so I can add it to my toolbox

Comment: I've edited out the CAPS LOCK from a couple of your answers, and I note that other people have done the same on other answers. Please stop using CAPS LOCK for your answers, I won't edit any more I will just recommend they are deleted

Comment: "Just take it to the local bike shop" not only doesn't answer the question, it's pretty bad advice in a lot of cases. I spend a lot of time re-fixing the bikes of friends and family which have just been received from local bike shops where they were serviced incorrectly. Last one was a $4,500 CF fancy bike that they allegedly put together, then delivered with a non-working rear derailleur and without the shim necessary to fix the seat height. There are good reasons many of us do all our own wrenching.